# URL Rewriting Question in Apache

Tags: php, apache, url-rewriting

I am doing a php project but I am not good at url_rewrite module in apache and I wanna learn how to achieve this kind of url rewrite here:

```
http://www.something.com/press/release/something_1/
```

`01` will be `id` of the press_release so that part will be dynamic part. `something` is also dynamic but not included in query_string part. This url is converted to the one below:

```
http://www.something.com/press/release/press_detail.php?rid=1
```

Can somebody show me how to write the url_rewrite rule for this conversion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place the following in the `.htaccess` file in your web root:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^press/release/.*_(\d+)/?$ press/release/press_detail.php?rid=$1 [QSA]
```

Comment: Sorry, but also something could be everything, it is dynamic but not included in query_string part.